# C# Project Type description for ProjectGuid

Tags: c#

I have found the `ProjectGuid` for my Visual Studio project in the `.csproj` file. Can I use this value to determine the type of the project?

I.e. Can I use a `ProjectGuid` such as this `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC` to determine the type is `Windows C# Application`? Or any other project type such as a `Database` project etc?

Comment: GUID is a Global Unique Identifier. There is no way for you to individually identify where that came from. You can never look up what that is from, unless you store the GUID from every control in a database. I think that the (Windows C#) part is only referencing how that GUID is made.

Comment: Check this link. You will get some useful info. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327202/what-are-the-project-guids-in-a-visual-studio-solution-file-used-for>

Answer (score 2):

You can see the list of project types at http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But How i can i determine the Project type Description by looking the Project GUID .Is there any place in Visual Studio or in the Project File where i can get the Project Type Description

Comment: As far as I know, there is no listing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911565/what-is-the-significance-of-projecttypeguids-tag-in-the-visual-studio-project-fi has some additional discussion but no resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Some are here.

Copied from [Julien Hoarau Answer on What is the significance of ProjectTypeGuids tag in the visual studio project file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911651/5858238)

```
Windows (C#)           {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
Windows (VB.NET)       {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
Windows (Visual C++)   {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
Web Application        {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
Web Site               {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
WCF                    {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
WPF                    {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
XNA (Windows)          {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
XNA (XBox)             {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
XNA (Zune)             {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}
Silverlight            {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
ASP.NET MVC            {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
ASP.NET MVC 4          {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}
Test                   {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
Solution Folder        {2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}
```