# How to find project type guid of existing projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution containing multiple projects. I went to properties -> application -> then in Assembly information I found one GUID, I checked this GUID on multiple sites to find out what type of project is it. but it isn't matching with any of those.
I think the GUID I need is the **Project Type GUID** and am not able to find this.
So where can I get this **Project Type GUID**?
(I am using VS-2013)

Answer (score 0):

There is no place in Visual Studio that explicitly shows "project type GUID", it is implicitly shown by set of features available to particular project.

The value found in "properties->application-> assembly information" is value used for assembly level [`GuidAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zszt3c4(v=vs.110).aspx) is assembly id for COM interop:

> Supplies an explicit System.Guid when an automatic GUID is undesirable.

This id is not related to "Project Type GUID" which is used by VS to enable/disable functionality.

Note: partial lists of project types can be found on multiple sites like http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs and discussed in [What are the project GUIDs in a Visual Studio solution file used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327202/what-are-the-project-guids-in-a-visual-studio-solution-file-used-for).