# The following projects do not have a valid ProjectGuid and were not built using a valid solution (.sln) thus will be skipped from analysis

Tags: sonarqube, .net-core

When you are building a dotnet core project with SonarQube you may be facing the error in the log:

> WARNING: The following projects do not have a valid ProjectGuid and were not built using a valid solution (.sln) thus will be skipped from analysis...

What should you do?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As dotnet core projects (.csproj) will not have `<ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>` tag specified in the default template this needs to be manually added.

So you need to edit the .csproj file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- other properties here -->

  <!-- SonarQube needs this -->
  <ProjectGuid>{E2CEBBAF-6DF7-41E9-815D-9AD4CF90C844}</ProjectGuid>
```

Make sure to place your own GUID inside the `<ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>` Tag

Comment: Hey, little late to the party, but how do you generate the project GUID? Or do you use the one generated in the .sln file ?

Comment: create a new one using e.g. https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx

Comment: So there is absolutely no connection between this GUID and the ones in the .sln file

Comment: Correct. There is no Connection.

Comment: Powershell to fix it      write-host "<ProjectGuid>{$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper())}</ProjectGuid>"

Comment: @PatrikLindström Thank you!  And you don't even need `Write-Host` if you're at a PowerShell command prompt

Comment: If a solution reference the project, you find the project's guid in the .sln.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. This is a very critical issue which has no proper solution. I have checked all possible way but didn't get proper solution. Applying your solution, i get to know this issue belongs to VS2017. Before that i was feeling so helpless. Thanks again to post a very useful solution for us.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Yes you are right you could hence pipe it to clip to get it into the clipboard directly  
 "<ProjectGuid>{$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper())}</ProjectGuid>" |clip

Comment: @Kobek, I believe there _is_ a connection, unlike what Daniel said in the comment. I just added a new answer to Daniel's old question here.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a solution to adding the missing xml elements in powershell.

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem -include *.csproj -Recurse
foreach($pathobject in $paths) 
{
    $path = $pathobject.fullname
    $doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $doc.Load($path)
    $child = $doc.CreateElement("ProjectGuid")
    $child.InnerText = "{"+[guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()+"}"
    $node = $doc.SelectSingleNode("//Project/PropertyGroup")
    $node.AppendChild($child)
    $doc.Save($path)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I think though that the GUID should be enclosed in {} to match Visual Studio, but maybe it works anyway?

Answer (score 8):

The solution I came up with is to build the solution, not the project files. If using Azure DevOps, use **/*.sln instead of **/*.csproj in your DotNetCoreCLI build step.

Comment: Definitely helped my Azure DevOps SonarQube steps, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed it for me in Azure DevOps

Comment: Thank you for sharing! This solved it for me using TeamCity and Sonar

Answer (score 1):

Note that the ProjectGuid can be found in the `.sln` file if you use such a file.

The `.sln` file has a long line similar to:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project1",
"path\Project1.csproj", "{307CB8DB-DC9C-4830-AA92-D842D89E17E0}"
```

In it, the first Guid (inside `Project(...)`) specifies the **type** of the project, and you can find a "dictionary" on the web that translates each Guid there to a human-readable type. For example, `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` means "C#" project type.

But **the last Guid** (given after the filename) **in the `.sln` entry is the ProjectGuid.**

So if you use an `.sln` file always, also from the SonarQube runs, there should be no need to insert a Guid in the `.csproj` file.

The other place the ProjectGuid can be specified is in the `.csproj`. Like other answers say, it looks like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- possibly other properties -->
    <ProjectGuid>{307CB8DB-DC9C-4830-AA92-D842D89E17E0}</ProjectGuid>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So if you never use `.sln` file in any context, you can just create any new Guid. In Visual Studio, you can use "Tools" - "Create GUID" - "Registry Format" to create a fresh Guid and and have it formatted correctly for this purpose.

However, from the above, it is clear that if you do use an `.sln` file in some contexts (like from Visual Studio during development/maintenance), but do not use that `.sln` file from the SonarQube run, then *the ProjectGuid you put in the `.csproj` should match the one present in the `.sln`.* One way you could achieve it, when creating new projects, is to first add the new project to the `.sln`, then do a diff ("Compare with Unmodified" or similar) on your `.sln` file using your version control software (like Git) to obtain the ProjectGuid, and copy/paste that Guid, including braces `{...}` into the new `.csproj` file.

Comment: See also [What are the project GUIDs in a Visual Studio solution file used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327202/)